# OptGroup in kendo ui combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

How to implement the groupings of item in kendo ui combobox with angular implementation. I tried

**k-template** but it is not working

```
<select kendo-combo-box
    k-placeholder="'Select frequency'"
    k-data-text-field="'Name'"
    k-data-value-field="'PaymentModeID'"
    k-filter="contains"
    k-auto-bind="false"
    k-template="freqTemplate"
    k-min-length="3"
    k-data-source="dsPaymentModes"
    style="width: 100%"></select>
```

When I searched I found that the telerik team didn't implement this functionality yet. Anybody have any alternative solution?

BTW I am using **Kendo UI v2014.2.1008** and I prepared a fiddle to play with. [Please click here](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/o5upo60m/5/)

Answer (score 0):

[demo kendo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/grouping)

Kendo UI v2015.2.805

new feature : **grouping** in combobox and dropdownlist.